# Add prefixe to all tags of an XmlObject

Tags: java, xml, dom, xmlbeans

I have xml String and i want to build a new Dom Element using this xml string by adding a prefix "peci" to all tags of this xml.
this is my code :

```
Document Effective_Change=null;                 
factory=XmlObject.Factory.parse(NewElement);
                    String testxml =factory.toString();
                    System.out.println(testxml);
                    DocumentBuilderFactory fact = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
                    fact.setNamespaceAware(true);
                    DocumentBuilder build; 
                    build = fact.newDocumentBuilder();
                    Effective_Change = build.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(testxml)));
                    Effective_Change.setPrefix("peci");
                     System.out.println(factory.xmlText());
```

at begining the tesxml contain :

```
<peci:xml-fragment xmlns:peci="urn:com.url/peci">
  <Derived_Event_Code>xx</Derived_Event_Code>
  <Effective_Moment>2018-07-23T04:20:04</Effective_Moment>
  <Entry_Moment>2018-07-23T04:20:04</Entry_Moment>
  <Person_Identification isUpdated="1">
    <Government_Identifier isDeleted="1">
      <Government_ID>xxxxx</Government_ID>
      <Government_ID_Type>xxxxxx/Government_ID_Type>
      <Issued_Date>xxxxx</Issued_Date>
    </Government_Identifier>
  </Person_Identification>
</peci:xml-fragment>
```

but i debeuged in this line

```
Effective_Change.setPrefix("peci");
```

i get this error :

```
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces.
    at org.apache.xerces.dom.NodeImpl.setPrefix(NodeImpl.java:701)
```

and what i want get as result is :

```
<peci:xml-fragment xmlns:peci="urn:com.url/peci">
  <peci:Derived_Event_Code>xx</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
  <peci:Effective_Moment>2018-07-23T04:20:04</peci:Effective_Moment>
  <peci:Entry_Moment>2018-07-23T04:20:04</peci:Entry_Moment>
  <peci:Person_Identification isUpdated="1">
    <peci:Government_Identifier isDeleted="1">
      <peci:Government_ID>xxxxx</peci:Government_ID>
      <peci:Government_ID_Type>xxxxxx</peci:Government_ID_Type>
      <peci:Issued_Date>xxxxx</peci:Issued_Date>
    </peci:Government_Identifier>
  </peci:Person_Identification>
</peci:xml-fragment>
```

Comment: e.g, `Derived_Event_Code` and `peci:Derived_Event_Code` are different names. You can't simply add a prefix to change one to the other. You must create a new element in the `urn:com.url/peci` namespace and replace the existing element with the new one.

Comment: How can i create new element with the prefix "peci" and conserve the same tag value as the old element?